# knockout custom bindinghandler and custom jquery UI widget

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a custom knockout bindingHandler to add a custom jQuery UI widget but have run into trouble trying to access the elements created during binding. I'm sure there's something fundamental about this that I'm missing. I have the following html:

```
    <table data-bind="myGrid: {}">
        <thead>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: { data: columns, as: 'column' }">
                <th data-bind="text: column"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: rows, as: 'row' }">
            <tr data-bind="foreach: { data: $parent.columns, as: 'column' }">
                <td data-bind="text: row[column]"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And the following javascript:

```
var vm = {
    columns: [
        'A', 'B'
    ],
    rows: []
};
$.widget("my.grid", {
    _create: function() {
        var columns = this.element.find('th');
    }
});
ko.bindingHandlers.myGrid = {
    init: function (element) {
        //$(element).grid();
    },
    update: function(element) {
        $(element).grid();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

When the widget is created, it needs to find each th element created from the binding. However, the elements don't appear to be created at that point in time. I have tried both the init and update methods of the bindinghandler.

This works if I manually add the widget to the element, just not within the bindinghandler.

When and how do I access the elements created from data-binding so that my jQuery widget can modify them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take control of the bindings to your descendant elements within your custom binding handler.

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html

But basically, do something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myGrid = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        // bind our child elements (which will create the virtual foreach elements)
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);  

        // make your grid widget
        $(element).grid();          

        // tell KO we have already bound the children
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function() { ... }
};
```